# D7 - hide the ajax_command_html message

Tags: 7, ajax

I'm using the following code to display a (success) message, it's working quite nicely, however I want it to disappear after, lets say 3 seconds.

```
  $commands = array();
  $commands[] = ajax_command_html('.ajax_messages', ' message ');
  $page = array(
  '#type' => 'ajax',
  '#commands' => $commands,
  );

  ajax_deliver($page);
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How to make it disappear is a javascript question. If you have such a javascript and want to integrate it with Drupal, this question is on topic, but currently I believe it's off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this in a js file included on the page.

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('.ajax_messages').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: nice this should work indeed, will test within a few hours and report back :)